# Eclipse not launching

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed Eclipse using Ubuntu Software Center. But Eclipse is not opening, when I click it is not opening or showing any error message it is very silent.

Output for `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

When I give Eclipse in terminal I am getting

```
The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

And when I give `sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
eclipse-platform is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Does /usr/bin/eclipse exist?

Comment: If not, try to remove Eclipse in Ubuntu Software Center and then install it using `apt-get install eclipse`.

Comment: no there is no eclipse in /usr/bin folder!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So, have you tried removing it in Ubuntu Software Center and then install it using `sudo apt-get install eclipse`?

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to run, from command line:

```
sudo apt-get -f install eclipse
```

**Alternative**:

[This](http://blog.brunobraga.net/eclipse-42-in-ubuntu-1204/) resource may be of help to you. I can confirm the process works on Ubuntu 14.04, as that is what I am using, and it cleanly upgraded my version of Eclipse to Kepler, and should resolve issues with your install. Here is the process, borrowed from the above link:

> 1. Run the below commands in a terminal:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get install -y oracle-jdk7-installer
>    update-alternatives --display java
>    ```
> 2. Be sure to check your Java version to make sure it's 1.7 or greater:
>
>    ```
>    java -version
>    ```
> 3. Download a version of Eclipse from [the website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). If you don't know what flavor to use, just use the Classic version.
> 4. Unpack the archive that you downloaded:
>
>    ```
>    cd Downloads
>    tar xvf [the file name you downloaded].tar.gz
>    ```
> 5. Back up your old Eclipse version (if any):
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv /usr/lib/eclipse /usr/lib/eclipse-old
>    ```
> 6. Move the version of Eclipse you downloaded to `/usr/lib`:
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv eclipse /usr/lib
>    ```
> 7. If this is a fresh install, you'll need to add a link to `/usr/bin` so you can run Eclipse:
>
>    ```
>    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
>    sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/eclipse
>    ```

**Note**: using this process, you will have to reinstall any plugins and re-add any update sources from previous build (at least, I did). However, you get a clean install of a newer version, which *should* resolve your issues. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Eclipse in the official repositories is too old and unsupported. The preferred way of installing Eclipse is using the official installer and running it.

First uninstall the package-manager's version of Eclipse:

```
$ sudo apt purge eclipse
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

Then download the official installer from [their website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and run it. The rest of the steps should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had not jre (java runtime environment) installed
So i did.

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

And it worked.